# Leveraging a Wikipedia bot to get results over 500

Tags: mediawiki, bots, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I am using MediaWiki APIs to fetch category members

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w//api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Physics&cmsort=timestamp&cmdir=desc&cmlimit=1000&format=json
```

However I get this message

```
"cmlimit may not be over 500 (set to 1000) for users
```

Is there any way I can leverage an existing bot to get all results?
If not, how can I get all results without using a bot?

Comment: See https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Continuing_queries.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to make more than one request, using the [continue parameter](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aQuery#Continuing_queries) to iterate over the result set.